# How to solve "ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info " problem on Linux Mint 19.3?

Tags: shell-script, linux-mint, python, python3, pip

I have Linux Mint 19.3 xfce.

When I am running any pip command (for eg 
this command

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I am getting error

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info
```

Please help

Comment: update setuptools using `pip install -U setuptools`. Try to install a package and provide us the exact error. It should show us the file location that is causing this problem.

Comment: @rubaiat see this [gist](https://gist.github.com/tekodetricks/4bbbcbc05de46b041eb609b665500493) for result of your suggestion. now what to do?

Comment: @rubaiat also see [this post](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1802040#p1802040) on linux mint forum.

Comment: Did you try [this gist](https://gist.github.com/tekodetricks/4bbbcbc05de46b041eb609b665500493#gistcomment-3270561)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I unknowingly upgraded system version of python which caused this error.

So while upgarding python **never use** `make install` but use `make altinstall`.

So problem was solved after reinstalling the OS.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this message highly depends on your requirements.txt. Can you create a very stripped down version that does nothing more than require a single package? Like this:

```bsh
#
# most minimalistic requirements.txt file
#
black
```

Then please run `pip install -r requirements.txt` with this file.

Comment: see this [gist](https://gist.github.com/tekodetricks/96c4f124c559b0bded24e1a77dccc62b) for result of suggested command applied in both non virtual and virtual env.

Comment: also see [this post](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1802040#p1802040) on linux mint forum.

Comment: Hi. Sorry, but I think should have been a comment, as opposed to an answer. You are essentially asking the OP to try something and provide more information.

Comment: @Pragyan Thanks for providing the output. It shows that you are trying to mix Python v2 and v3 in the same virtual environment. You should avoid doing so. Unless you have specific requirements that explicitly ask for using Python 2, please just stick to Python 3. Then create a virtual environment (`python3 -m venv myenvname`), use it (`source myenvname/bin/activate`) and run pip (`pip3 install -r requirements.txt`). Doable?

Comment: @Time4Tea Totally agree. I just can't post comments (yet). Thus, the only other option would have been to not post anything at all. I'm happy to update the answer to actually be helpful (once that's possible).

Comment: @rolando I was having problems because I unknowingly upgraded system version so the files messed up.

Comment: @Pragyan Are these problems resolved now? (Upgrading the system's Python is not the best of all ideas, granted. But personally, I don't second that one necessarily needs to reinstall the whole system just because of this.)

Comment: @rolando  Ok, sounds good. If you update your answer, then ping me in the comments and I will upvote (if it seems helpful).